# Prove this set is bounded below

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove this set is bounded below $A = \{\frac1n : n\in \mathbb N^+\}$ knowing that
${\alpha}$ is the infimum of A.

Could i get some help? I thought proving this by contradiction but i am getting nowhere.

Comment: If you just want bounded below, any negative number would work.  If you want the infimum, draw a picture and you might be able to guess that that is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as proof strategies, write down the definition of a set that is bounded below, which may involve writing the definition of a lower bound. Then, try drawing this set on the real number line. The first of this will help clarify what your goal is, what you want to show, and the second of these should give you intuition as to how you're going to show this.

Now, having done this, let us show that $A$ is bounded below. We will show specifically that $A$ is bounded below by $0$. So, let $\frac{1}{n} \in A$. We know that in any ordered field, including $\mathbb{R}$, $0 < 1$. Then, we can use this to prove by induction that $0 < 1 \leq n$ for all natural $n$. Having done this, we then know that $0 < \frac{1}{n}$, as if $\frac{1}{n} \leq 0$, then $1 = n \cdot \frac{1}{n} \leq 0$, by the ordered field axioms.

Of course, this was all possibly more detailed than it needed to be; normally I would just say that $0 < \frac{1}{n}$ and be done with it, but I felt that excruciating detail would help here.